# How to mock static method while using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junit4, jmockit

I need to mock a static method. I know of two tools to help do this: PowerMockito and JMockit, both of which require usage of the @RunWith annotation. However, I've already used @RunWith for SpringRunner to set up some @Autowired dependencies, and [it seems you can't use @RunWith twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431427/multiple-runwith-statements-in-junit).

[I see that PowerMockito has a PowerMockRunnerDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147060/cannot-run-powermockrule-with-springjunit4classrunner-in-spring-boot-project), which looks promising. But for various reasons, I'm stuck using JMockit for now. Is there a JMockit equivalent for this?

I essentially need to mock a static method and set up @Autowired dependencies for my test at the same time.

Comment: JMockit never required use of `@RunWith`. It *supported* it a while ago, but not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can circumvent the need to use any specialized static mocking tool by [wrapping the static method call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44967314/10137647).

Comment: JMockit is not a "specialized" mocking tool. In fact, it is more "feature complete" than any other mocking library for Java. It has actually become a lot more than a mocking library. I personally use it more for integration tests, rather than unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of jmockit (1.49) does not utilize the @RunWith annotation.  Instead, it has you setup a javaagent as a vmarg.  There's full documentation on the jmockit site: https://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Introduction.html#runningTests.   I'd definitely encourage you to use JMockIt rather than the EasyMock+PowerMock combo, JMockIt is self-contained and handles statics naturally.